# Clip a DSM by raster extent in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, clip

I am trying to clip a DSM by raster extent in QGIS. Both rasters have the same PCS (EPSG: 26911). My results appear a bit off axis from raster extent. Attached a picture; clipped DSM underneath original clipping extent. I am trying to have the DSM match the orientation of the true colour raster. [image]

Comment: The extent of the raster is the bounding box in the current map projection, that's why the clip doesn't match the raster. What is the projection of the map project? Does it match the raster? If not, set the project projection to match the raster (EPSG:26911) and see if the raster is now axis aligned. If so, you'll be able to do the clip you want.